# Phonegap androing app hyperlink page loading

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

i am developing android native application using HTML5 and Jquery mobile framework, i used `phonegap build` features for build my application `apk` file, anyway my application working well any android devices,

my question is i had added a hyperlink link inside my application, for example:

```
<a href="http://google.com"> tap me</a>
```

when we tap thhis hyperlink a new site will open same window, but between tap and new site index page opening time there is too much delay, almost 5 seconds, i think its because of loading new web pages, this 5 seconds my application just still... so user don't know if new page loading or anything error... i need to put a loading text or just animated `gif` image between this 5 seconds gap like jquery mobile page loading...

any idea.?  thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery Mobile, you can use the Page Loading Widget to show a message or spinner while the new data/page loads

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html

```
<a class="show-page-loading-msg" href="http://google.com">Tap me</a>
```

Add an event handler for this link (and others like it):

```
$(document).on('tap', '.show-page-loading-msg', function () {
    $.mobile.loadingMessage();
});
```

Comment: its not possible for my case, because what i asked that not for same domain web page, i gave another domain link address, when we give same domain path link your solutions working, but for different domain its not working, still delay or empty page while loading link page, i need loading widget for other domain link... any idea..?

Comment: Maybe try cancelling the event, setting the message and then changing the window.location to follow the link?

$(document).on('tap', '.show-page-loading-msg', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.mobile.loadingMessage();
    window.location = this.href;
});